Dell server power configurtion with Ansible
I`m writing an Ansible playbook to configure Dell servers and I can't find an "AC power recovery" option in "dellemc.openmanage". Are there any options to configure AC power recovery to ON state within Ansible playbook? I found power options module "redfish_powerstate", but I understood it will work once (as playbook will be running).
Thank you in advance
